# What is the name of the property for two random variables having disjoint supports?

Tags: probability, random-variable

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables.  There is a specific name for the property when the support for $X$ is disjoint from the support for $Y$.  I can't remember it, and I can't seem to find it in search results.  What is the name of that property?

---

More rigorously, let $R_X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the values that $X$ will take with nonzero probability

$$
R_X = \arg \inf_{A \subset \mathbb{R}} \{ P(X \in A) = 1, A \, \text{closed} \}
$$

Similarly, let $R_Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the values that $Y$ will take with nonzero probability.

$$
R_Y = \arg \inf_{B \subset \mathbb{R}} \{ P(Y \in B) = 1, B \, \text{closed} \}
$$

Say $R_X \cap R_Y = \emptyset$.  What is this property called?

Comment: Your $R_X$ and $R_Y$ do not make any sense, because they are not well defined.  The infima of those probabilities are *always* zero, no matter what the random variables $X$ and $Y$ might be, and--by definition of infimum--both $R_X$ and $R_Y$ are *numbers,* not subsets of real numbers, and definitely not the supports of the variables!  Often, the support of a variable is taken to be the smallest closed set with probability $1.$ Getting the definition correct is crucial because it determines whether the answer you posted is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that.  I made an edit yesterday to a definition based on infimum, and didn’t fully consider it I suppose!  Fixed.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "arg inf"?  I would guess you mean something like $$R_X=\bigcap_{A\subset \mathbb R \mid P(X\in A)=1}\bar A$$ where $\bar A$ is the closure of $A.$ If that's the case, then having disjoint supports *implies,* but is not equivalent to, mutual singularity of the distributions.

Comment: [arg inf](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1436838/426612) is similar to arg min.  Its result is the minimizing argument rather than the minimized quantity.  Also I believe the my answer only claims implication, not equivalence.  If you provide feedback to make that clearer, that would be wonderful.

Comment: The initial assertion in your answer takes the form of "this property *is*...;" one usually interprets "is" as "is equivalent to."  I agree you attempt a proof only in one direction.

Comment: Good call.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

After more research, the nearest property I can find is [singularity of measure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure)  I don't think it's correct to say that random variables are themselves singular, but we can say it of their distributions.  I'll leave this answer unaccepted, just in case someone has a better answer.

---

Specifically, say the random variables $X, Y$ have the respective supports $R_X, R_Y$ disjoint as defined in the question, with distributions (or laws) $P^X, P^Y$.

Then $P^X, P^Y$ are [singular.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure)  Denoted $P^X \perp P^Y$

#### Proof:

By definition of [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory) for probability distributions, we have that $P^X(R_X) = 1$.

Since we have assumed $R_X \cap R_Y = \emptyset$, we know that $R_Y \subset R_X^C$.

Also, $P^X(R_X^C) = 1 - P^X(R_X) = 1 - 1 = 0$.

Similarly, $P^Y(R_Y) = 1$ and $P^Y(R_Y^C) = 0$.

But $P^X(R_X^C) = 0 \implies P^X(R_Y) = 0$ by monotonicity of measure.

So we have that there exists $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$ and $P^X(A) = 0$ and $P^Y(B) = 0$.  So $P^X, P^Y$ are singular. $\square$

---

Note that, as per @whuber's comments, this only proves implication.  The converse is not true. As a counterexample, consider two random variables, one distributed uniformly over the closed unit interval, and the other distributed by Dirac delta centered in the midpoint:

$$
X \sim \text{Uniform}[0,1]\\
Y \sim \delta(\frac{1}{2})
$$

$P^X$ and $P^Y$ are mutually singular since $P^X(\{ \frac{1}{2} \}) = 0$ and $P^Y(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ \frac{1}{2} \} ) = 0$, but the support of the former $R_X = [0,1]$ contains the support of the latter $R_Y = \{ \frac{1}{2} \}$.

Comment: +1. As an example of two distributions that have singular measures but whose supports are *not* disjoint, consider a Bernoulli variable $X$ and a variable $Y$ with uniform distribution on any open interval $U$ containing $0.$ The support of $Y$ is the closure of $U$ which has nonempty intersection with the support of $X$ (which is $\{0,1\}$).

Comment: Thanks for the example making non-equivalence clear.  That's important.  In fact I think I'll call that out in the answer explicitly.